# How to query user's language choice in innosetup script?

Tags: desktop-application, multilingual, inno-setup

How to know what language user have selected to install setup in innosetup ? Im using innosetup 5.3 to package my application, its an multilingual application and so it would be useful if i knew what language user has selected to install the package.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.5.3? do you mean the current version (5.3)? if so if you have:

```
[Languages]
Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:english.isl"
...
```

you can return the language "**en**" via the `{language}` constant.

Comment: you can return the language "en" via the {language}  constant.
Where and how do i get this {language} constant , do u have any sample for this. Thanks

Comment: You can use it in inno directives like:
`Filename: "C:\XXX\{Language}\some.file`
It depends on what you want to do with the "en" string

Answer (score 6):

Try this method to determine what language user selected:

```
[Code]
var
  ResultLan: String;

procedure MyConst();    
begin
  ResultLan := ExpandConstant('{language}');    
  MsgBox(ResultLan, mbInformation, MB_OK);        
end;
```

Pina